# How to create a custom home page template?

Tags: 7

I've built a few drupal sites, and always end up creating a content type for Home Page so that I can have a custom template for my home page content, however it seems excessive to have a whole content type just for this. Is there a better way to have a custom home page template?

Wordpress has the front-page template, is there something like that for Drupal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes : https://www.drupal.org/node/317461

> In Drupal 7, copy the page.tpl.php file and name it page--front.tpl.php.

Copy the file in your sites/all/themes/yourtheme/templates file (and then clear the caches of your site)